# ¿Como visulizar en pantallasecundaria datos procesados en pantalla principal en flutter?

Tags: flutter, diseño-de-clases, widget

Agradezco algo de apoyo, actualmente me encuentro estancada con mi codigo en flutter. Estoy desarrollando una aplicación que recibe y envía datos por SSH, esto lo hace de forma continúa. La conexión con el cliente ssh la hace en la pagina principal o clase,pero requiero que estos datos que se obtienen en la pagina principal se visualicen en pagina secundaria sin detener la conexión ssh.

Para realiza la conexión de cliente ssh estoy usando paquete **dartssh2**. He intentado utilizar ***provider*** pero no he obtenido resultado deseado, los valores no se actualizan en pagina secundaria, tengo que volver a primera pagina para que el valor cambie.

Comment: Te podríamos ayudar mejor si defines parte de tu código, así sabremos que pasa con tu aplicación.

Comment: Buenas, Laura. recuerda pasarte por la sección como preguntar. Este tipo de preguntas pueden terminar cerradas o no recibir el apoyo que buscas. Una pregunta bien planteada debe mostrar siempre el código de lo que has intentado, ser específica y centrarse en una única duda y estar bien redactada; en tu caso, faltaría mostrar el código de lo que llevas intentado. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

ChangeNotifier.

Veo que aquí tienes varios problemas de entender el concepto de Provider.

Te daré una explicación breve.

ChangeNotifier es parte de flutter y este notifica cuando hay algún cambio dentro de este widget.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Calculadora extends ChangeNotifier{

  var _total;
  get total() => _total;
  
  void suma(int a, int b){
    _total = a + b;
    notifierListener();  ///Esto te ayuda a actualizar el _total y con esto activa el notifier y en cualquier lugar de tu clase que sea hija de esta clase podrá llegar la notificación.
  }
}
```

entonces con Provider podrías ocupar un Consumer o tambien podrías estar escuchando con Provider.of(context, listen:true); **aunque este ultimo no te lo recomiendo

```
 Consumer<Calculadora>(
      builder: (_, mydata, __) => Text(mydata.getTotal().toString()),
    },
```

Con esto te mantendrías escuchando cuando el notifier te notifique cualquier cambio de tus widget padre.

Te recomiendo revisar un poco acerca de esto:

https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html

También estarīa perfecto si nos compartieras un poco de tu código.

Comment: Buenas, recuerda que aunque lo hagas por ayudar, no es recomendable dar soporte a preguntas mal planteadas, como lo sería esta. Una pregunta de este tipo debe ir acompañada de lo que ha intentado la persona en cuestión.